# Why does OWASP recommend to never return JSON arrays not wrapped in objects?

Tags: json

[AJAX Security Cheat Sheet § Always return JSON with an Object on the outside](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#always-return-json-with-an-object-on-the-outside) says:

> Always have the outside primitive be an object for JSON strings:
>
> **Exploitable**:
>
> `[{"object": "inside an array"}]`
>
> **Not exploitable**:
>
> `{"object": "not inside an array"}`
>
> **Also not exploitable**:
>
> `{"result": [{"object": "inside an array"}]}`

Sadly, they don't provide a rationale, at least not in the cheatsheet.

Why is that so?

As far as I'm aware, [the possible attack here is Javascript array constructor poisoning, but that's been fixed for a long time already (in ES 5)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159609/how-is-it-possible-to-poison-javascript-array-constructor-and-how-does-ecmascrip).

Am I missing something?

Comment: See comments on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262844/how-this-json-object-can-be-exploitable

Answer (score 5):

The OWASP does provide a rationale by referencing the [Angular documentation on the underlying attack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#json-vulnerability-protection) (which is exactly the Array constructor attack you already mentioned). There's also a [slightly more detailed explanation](https://angular.io/guide/security#cross-site-script-inclusion-xssi) in another part of the documentation.

Both the OWASP and Angular also explicitly point out this protection is aimed at *older browsers* -- or to put it more bluntly: This is for ancient versions of Internet Explorer, Firefox etc. which hopefully no user still visit websites with.

So this particular protection can probably be phased out now -- except for very special circumstances. However, it's definitely a good idea to protect sensitive JSON data as a precaution. For example, if you use session cookies to authenticate the Ajax HTTP requests, [cookie prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#cookie_prefixes) and the [`SameSite` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value) allow you to restrict the cookies to same-origin or same-site requests, so that any cross-site leak (due to future or currently unknown vulnerabilities) becomes less likely. As a nice side effect, this also works as a second layer of defense against cross-site request forgery.